# Should I add src/MAlonzo to .gitignore?

Tags: agda

Compiling my Agda code results in a `src/MAlonzo` directory being created. (Where `src/MyProject` is where my Agda code lives.) It contains a bunch of `.hs` (Haskell) and `.o` (object) files.

Is there anything in this directory that I should commit, or do people typically add `/src/MAlonzo` to their `.gitignore`?

I'm asking because I'm surprised that build artifacts are being put in the `src` directory instead of the `_build` directory. I wonder if there's a reason for that.

Comment: > I wonder if there's a reason for that.

It's purely historical. `_build` was introduced for `.agdai` files and none of the backends (MAlonzo, latex, html) were modified so that their output would be in `_build/` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. MAlonzo is the [GHC backend](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/compilers.html#ghc-backend) used for compiling and running Agda programs. Everything there is automatically generated from your Agda source files.